# Why does the nested list of html is not working?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

There is something wrong in the following code. I want `Add Result` and `Manage Result` to come under `Result`. Also `Add1 Result` and `Add2 Result` should come under `Add Result`, i.e, it is a problem of nested list. But my code is not working. Any suggestion please

```html
<li class="has-children">
  <a href="#"> <span>Result</span> </a>
  <ul class="child-nav">
    <li class="has-children">
      <a href="add-result.php"><span>Add Result</span></a>
      <ul class="child-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="add1-results.php"> <span>Add1 Result</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="add2-results.php"> <span>Add2 Result</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="manage-results.php"> <span>Manage Result</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: Everything works for me here. Please, clarify.

Comment: After click on Result, all three options Add1 Result, Add2 Result and Manage Result appears simultaneously. But if I click on Add Result once, then the problem disappears. Also there is no indentation in Add1 Result and Add2 result wrt Add Result.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I can see with your code is that your first `li` element is not inside an `ol` or `ul` element, which [is required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)

```html
<ul>
  <li class="has-children">
    <a href="#"> <span>Result</span> </a>
    <ul class="child-nav">
      <li class="has-children">
        <a href="add-result.php"><span>Add Result</span></a>
        <ul class="child-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="add1-results.php"> <span>Add1 Result</span></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="add2-results.php"> <span>Add2 Result</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="manage-results.php"> <span>Manage Result</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```